# number of dentry and i-node

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3

I had the following question on an exam:

*In a ext3 filesystem the number of dentries is higher than the number of i-nodes.*

I had to answer with True or False and explain.

My answer:

*It is false because dentries are links between directories, and basically everything is an i-node ( even a directory ) so # i-nodes > # dentries.*

However i haven't taken into cosideration the ext3 file-system. Is there something I missed or my answer is correct ?

Answer (score 4):

We'll probably have more dentries due to the following:

1. All hardlinks have unique dentries, but point to the same inode.
2. Lookups returning ENOENT (file or directory does not exist) creates a dentry and marks its inode pointer as NULL(which is technically called a negative dentry). This helps is quickening up negative lookups, ie lookup on non-existent path.

Answer (score 1):

But you can have hardlinks. So you can reasonably have many dentries pointing at the same inode.

Comment: But most likely there are more i-nodes than dentries... I mean yeah, it's possible what you said, but very unlikely :x.

Comment: @QtLearner That's beyond the scope of my answer.

Comment: If you were to grade my answer with 0 or 1 what would you give?

Answer (score 1):

The number of dentries is *always* higher than the number of inodes in a cleanly unmounted filesystem.

Consider: Every inode (excluding unlinked files that are kept alive through open file handles - these are purged in a clean unmount, or during recovery after an unclean unmount) has at least one dentry associated with it. Every directory inode has at least two - a link from its parent (or its own `..` for the root) and from `.`. Additionally directories have an additional dentry associated with them for each subdirectory's `..` dentry.

Thus, at an absolute minimum, there is one more dentry than inode (for a FS with only the root directory). Additional directories and hardlinks inflate this further.

Comment: I don't know enough to judge if this is correct, but if it is then it seems like the most clear and useful answer, so +1.